# CookieCollection issue when cookie's Path is not set

Tags: c#, .net, cookies, .net-4.0

I'm using `HttpWebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse` to crawl a site. I'm using the same `CookieContainer` for each request, ensuring the cookies are handled automatically.

However, one of the requests requires a specific cookie, which is set in a previous response. Although this is present in the collection, its `Path` property appears incorrect. According to [RFC2109](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt) (Page 7) when a cookie is set with a blank Path (as this one is), the Path should be set to the URL of the request up to but not including the final slash. What's actually happening is that it is being set to the *entire* URL path, which means that the cookie cannot be subsequently read by a different URL in the same subdomain.

An example:

1. I request the page at http://www.myserver.com/sub/mypage.php
2. The response includes a `Set-Cookie` header, which reads *mycookie=12345;
   expires=Wed, 27-Jun-2012 16:20:00 GMT*
3. The cookie is added to the .NET CookieCollection. As there is no Path set, the Path is
   incorrectly intialised to */sub/mypage.php*
4. I request another page under the same subdomain, but which requires the mycookie cookie, e.g. http://www.myserver.com/sub/anotherpage.php
5. The cookie is not served by .NET because the Path does not exactly match. If the Path was */sub*, it would have been served correctly

I have performed the same navigation steps using the Firefox browser with Firebug and Firecookie extensions. The Path is set correctly, i.e. to the subdomain, in the real browser session.

Can anyone confirm this and possibly point me to a workaround or fix for this issue? Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the bit of internal code in question. Doesn't look like an accidental bug. You should report the issue if its not following the standard though.

```
switch (this.m_cookieVariant)
{
    case CookieVariant.Plain:
        this.m_path = absolutePath;
        break;

    case CookieVariant.Rfc2109:
        this.m_path = absolutePath.Substring(0, absolutePath.LastIndexOf('/'));
        break;

    default:
        this.m_path = absolutePath.Substring(0, absolutePath.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        break;
}
```

So it uses the Plain cookie variant unless specified otherwise in the cookie itself.

You are going to have to iterate over all the cookies checking. Really this is 1 of the many reasons I hate .net's cookie handling. Can't easily get all the domains/cookies. Simplest fix would be to do the following. However you will end up with duplicate cookies. So you may want to get the cookies by the uri instead.

```
public static CookieCollection FixCookies(CookieCollection collection)
{
    foreach (Cookie cookie in collection)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cookie.Path))
            continue;

        int idx = cookie.Path.LastIndexOf('/');
        if (idx == -1)
            continue;

        cookie.Path = cookie.Path.Substring(0, idx);
    }
    return collection;
}

[STAThread]
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var http = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/test/test.php");
    http.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    var resp = (HttpWebResponse)http.GetResponse();
    http.CookieContainer.Add(FixCookies(resp.Cookies));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Will. It looks like .NET defaults a cookie to the 'Plain' Version0 variant (from the original Netscape implementation), which I'm not sure is actually correct. I'm interested to find out if and where Version and CookieVariant are overridden internally, but until then I'll stick with the solution you recommend to get around the issue. Thanks again!

Comment: The variant gets set by sending a cookie like 'mycookie=12345; expires=Wed, version=1, port=80'. Setting version will set it variant to Rfc2109. Setting the port will instead set it to Rfc2965.