# HttpClient assigns other path information to cookies as browsers do

Tags: c#, cookies, dotnet-httpclient

I am using `HttpClient` to consume a website. The website uses cookies, but one of the cookies has no `path` data assigned. HttpClient will use the relative path to the requested file as path information, while browsers only use the directory information.

Example:

```
Request-URL:
https://someurl.org/dir1/file.php  

HttpClient:
path=/dir1/file.php  

browser:
path=/dir1
```

The C# behavior is problematic since the cookie would only be sent to that specific file instead of all files in the same directory. As a workaround I am extracting that cookie, makeing a copy, assign the correct path to the copy, mark the original as expired and than adding the copy to the cookie container.

This works, but may be there is a better more offical option to make the HttpClient act like a browser in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231226/cookiecollection-issue-when-cookies-path-is-not-set) question is very similar to my own question (instead of `HttpClient` (my scenario) `HttpWebRequest` is used directly) and it also puts more background information to the problem.

Altough, I didn't end up with the solution provided there, I did modify the answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15588214/how-to-manage-cookies-with-httpclient-when-using-a-mocking-httpmessagehandler) question to extend a `DelegatingHandler` and managing the cookies myself (fixing the problem by inserting path information if missing) instead of letting the `HttpMessageHandler` handle the cookies.

```
public class FixMissingPathOnPlainCookiesHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    public CookieContainer Container { get; private set; }

    public FixMissingPathOnPlainCookiesHandler(HttpClientHandler clientHandler, CookieContainer cc = null) 
        : base(clientHandler)
    {
        if (clientHandler == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(clientHandler));
        if (clientHandler.UseCookies)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The HttpClientHandler property '.UseCookies' must be false");

        Container = cc ?? new CookieContainer();
    }

        
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var uri = request.RequestUri;

        var cookies = Container.GetCookieHeader(uri);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cookies))
            request.Headers.Add("Cookie", cookies);

        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        if (response.Headers.TryGetValues("Set-Cookie", out var cookieHeaders))
        {
            foreach (var cookie in cookieHeaders)
            {
                var local = cookie;

                if (local.IndexOf("path=", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == -1)
                    local += "; path=" + uri.AbsolutePath.Substring(0, uri.AbsolutePath.LastIndexOf('/'));
                    
                Container.SetCookies(uri, local);
            }
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```